# Assigning permission - lengthy feature list experience

Tags: controls, scrolling, view

[image]

Task: User can assign the feature to applications.

Problem statement:
1. Need to show all 25 feature list to user but in a better way.
Is it a good experience to show all 25 features with UI Controls(not just toggle but can be text box, dropdown) on the screen?

Any suggestions are welcome. Happy to help with further details, if required!!

Answer (score 1):

#### Grouping

Grouping the features would go a long way. If there are meaningful groups of features, use those. Focus on one group at a time, with the other groups visible but out of focus.
This can be done with tabs or collapsible sections, for instance.

#### Defaults and Exceptions

You didn't ask about this, but you could provide a way to set the options for all programs at once, highlighting the exceptions where a specific program doesn't follow the rest of the programs. Especially if the list of programs grows larger, this will help the user focus on the special cases.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @sqb 'd defaults and exceptions recommendation.

A medical client once gave me requirements for 3 different settings that patients & medics could choose for their records. In response I designed something very much like you have here - option 1: choose a b or c; option 2: choose a b or c etc etc.

> The client took one look at the design and said 'this would never happen'.

In reality, people are likely to have a goal (see Lucy Suchman's 'Plans and Situated Actions'.) that is related to their current action or situation.

> E.g. 'I want to change the settings on all my records to option a' (edge case in my scenario)
>
> OR 'I want to change the setting on This record, right now, because of a specific reason' (More likely case).

**menu vs smorgasbord**

In the end I responded with a view-style menu. You could then drill down to change them individually.

My first design was more like a smorgasbord - I was presenting them with everything on the table, when all they wanted was a menu where they could pick out the thing they already wanted.